# Can we skip some pre-defined Frames while rendering, to prevent blender from re-rednering the same scene?

Tags: rendering

I am an animator on blender and i want to know that Can we skip some per-defined Frames while rendering, to prevent blender from re-rendering the same scene?

Because while rendering there are scenes in which camera stops for a while and all of the objects are stopped and only audio is playing in the back. So for that period let say camera and objects stops for 4- 5 seconds which means at 24Fps 120 Frames will be re-rendered again and again although they are ditto same. Is there any feature in blender 2.81 version else i will have to manually skip them which is a time taking task.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/108562/how-to-list-the-frame-numbers-which-contain-keyframes-in-python

Answer (score 0):

If your output is set to be .png images (which is recommended) you can change the duration of any frame of your choice in the video editor. If you want your output to be video you can set the Frame Start and End in the Scene Tab, render the first sequence, then the frame where you want to stop, and for last render the rest of the animation. after that, you would put everything together in the video editor.

Comment: I couldnt clearly understand. How can i change the duration of any frame? Its a single frame thats it.
2ndly if i manually start and stop in whole animation then it will waste a lot of my time. Isnt there any automated method?