# Rendering a specific set of frames at different time

Tags: python, rendering, animation

Good day, I am looking for a way to tell Blender to render a set of frames, stop and render another set of frames using python. For example, my project has 500 frames and I want Blender to render the first 100 frames (from frame 1 to 100), stop, then move on to render frames 101 to 200, stop, then move on to render frames 201 to 300, up til frame 500. Of course, Blender needs to save all the rendered images in .png format.

I know there is a way to render a frame like

****bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = '/home/user/Documents/image.jpg'
bpy.ops.render.render(write_still = True)****

but that only tells Blender to render one frame at one time. I know I can incorporate this into a for loop but since I have little knowledge in python and in programming in general I had a difficult time putting it together.

The reason doing so is that I've encountered a weird problem in Blender Render recently that Blender will freeze when rendering 144 in a row. So my approach to the solution is to try to programmatically render 100 frames at a time then move on to the next 100 frames until all 500 frames are rendered.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Somewhat related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/108562/how-to-list-the-frame-numbers-which-contain-keyframes-in-python  ie render from command line, well explained in answer here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/131052/how-to-render-in-command-line

Comment: Do you have persistent images on?