# Script to skip frames with no animation

Tags: python

I found a script (here: [Can frames with no animation be automatically skipped?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15649/can-frames-with-no-animation-be-automatically-skipped/28960)) that should do exactly what I need. But When I add it to the text editor and press run in Blender it does nothing.
How do I get it running please? (I really have no clue how codes work, so explaining it to me like to an idiot would be very much appreciated.)

````
import bpy
import subprocess
import os
import shutil

def render_with_skips(start, stop):
    """
    Take start and stop, and render animation only for animated
    frames. Still frames, are substituted into the output folder
    as copies of their equivalents.
    """

    render_range = list(range(start, stop))

    # create JSON like dictionary to store each
    # animated object's fcurve data at each frame.
    all_obj_fcurves = {}
    for obj in bpy.data.objects:    
        obj_fcurves = {}

        try:
            obj.animation_data.action.fcurves
        except AttributeError:
            print("--|'%s' is not animated" % obj.name)
            continue

        print("\n--> '%s' is animated at frames:" % obj.name)

        for fr in list(range(start,stop+1)):
            fc_evals = [c.evaluate(fr) for c in obj.animation_data.action.fcurves]
            obj_fcurves.update({int(fr): fc_evals})
            print(fr, end=", ")
        print()

        all_obj_fcurves.update({obj.name: obj_fcurves})


    # loop through each animated object and find its
    # animated frames. then remove those frames from
    # a set containing all frames, to get still frames.
    still_frames = set(render_range)
    for obj in all_obj_fcurves.keys():
        obj_animated_frames = []
        for i, fr in enumerate(sorted(all_obj_fcurves[obj].keys())):
            if i != 0:
                if all_obj_fcurves[obj][fr] != all_obj_fcurves[obj][fr_prev]:
                    obj_animated_frames.append(fr)
            fr_prev = fr

        still_frames = still_frames - set(obj_animated_frames)

    print("\nFound %d still frames" % len(still_frames))
    print(sorted(still_frames), end="\n\n")


    # render animation, skipping the still frames and
    # filling them in as copies of their equivalents
    filepath = bpy.context.scene.render.filepath

    for fr in render_range:
        if fr not in still_frames or fr == render_range[0]:
            bpy.context.scene.frame_set(fr)
            bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = filepath + '%04d' % fr
            bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)
        else:
            scene = bpy.context.scene
            abs_filepath = scene.render.frame_path(scene.frame_current)
            #abs_path = '/'.join(abs_filepath.split('/')[:-1]) + '/'
            print("Frame %d is still, copying from equivalent" % fr)
            scn = bpy.context.scene
            shutil.copyfile(filepath + '%04d.png' % (fr-1), filepath + '%04d.png' % fr)

    bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = filepath

start = bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].frame_start
end = bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].frame_end
render_with_skips(start,end)
```
````

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: I use Windows 10.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/108562/how-to-list-the-frame-numbers-which-contain-keyframes-in-python/108588#108588  Also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1718/is-it-possible-to-render-only-keyframes-from-dope-sheet/23196#23196 to set up a more printer like range _eg_ frames  `1, 3, 4-40, 50`